# What tag should I add for a custom datePicker?

Tags: html, web, frontend, accessibility

I'm currently developing a custom datepicker for a banking application.
The idea is to have the page structured in the best way possible, specially for accessibility.

I currently disabled the browser's default pop up when you click on a `input(type="date")` element. and I do display my own calendar, it is currently a `<div>` and it works fine

What `html` tag should I use for that "pop-up" calendar that will be displayed displayed on top of the input, and over the page in a higher z-index?

I'm thinking it could be a `<dialog>` but what do you guys think?

Comment: You're sure you want to implement it from scratch? There are a couple of datepickers for different javascript frameworks. The tag containing your calendar could just be a div. It is anyhow up to you/the library to style it.

Comment: I already did the implementation  of the whole calendar myself, i was not allowed to use any external libraries and i had to do it from scratch. It wasn't easy but it was possible. I just want to know if its okay to just have it in a div or if it should be a dialog

Comment: good job! div is fine.

Comment: we need to see the outputted HTML to be able to guide you. Datepickers are particularly tricky from an accessibility perspective. You need to consider appropriate `aria` such as `aria-owns`, `aria-expanded` and `aria-selected`. You also need to consider keyboard navigation, correct semantics (should it be a table, a list of buttons...) etc. a `<dialog>` is not a bad choice but you will need more `aria` and to use polyfills as support is not great https://caniuse.com/#feat=dialog. Add your HTML & I will add some pointers to an answer (it won't be a complete answer as I can't test it without JS)